# How to copy bytea from Postgres to Oracle

Tags: oracle, postgresql, bytea

I have a Postgres 9.1 table **plines** with a bytea field **shape**.

Number of records is about 500000.

What is the best way to copy bytea data **plines.shape** from Postgres to  a field **shape** of an Oracle 10g table **olines**?

Thank you in advance, ysa

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a program in Java which would connect to PostgreSQL (using [JDBC PostgreSQL driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/)) and Oracle (using [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)) simultaneously and then read a row from Postgres, put this row to Oracle table, repeat.

This would be much easier [the other way around](http://oracle-fdw.projects.postgresql.org/)... ;-)